# How to create a Calendar Home Widget in android?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I tried to implement a calendar application, i referred this link http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-simple-calender-in-gridview.html for my calendar development, now i wish to add my calendar in android home widget screen, i searched on Google, unfortunately i couldn't get the correct solution.

My Requirements are,

1. Create a Calender widget.
2. In My calendar activity i have to Option menu, One is "Add to Widget", when i click this, my calendar will enable on the Home Widget. The another one is cancel, when i click this back to main activity.
3. Add my Calender into android home widget. (please refer this image)

   [image]

Any one have the solution please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is *too* general, perhaps you are trying to ask "how do I get a calendar view in a home screen widget"?

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a widget via an Activity. Some custom launchers (like Go Launcher) have special APIs or features where you can, but stock does not.

Comment: Some sample widget creation code are available in Google, i tried that but i don't know how to implement it to calender.